# How to pass single data API data textview

Tags: android, rest, textview

I tried it. I don't see any data. If you find any errors in these please let me know.The data is coming to me from the rest API

```
public class newsfeed implements Serializable {
    public int cid = -1;
    public String category_name;
   
}

private TextView category_name;

category_name = root_view.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);

public void displayData(final newsfeed newsfeed) {    
   category_name.setText(newsfeed.category_name);       
}
```

How to set rest API single data?